# Android - On back press

Tags: java, android

I am writing a code for `onBackPressed()` method.
Actually, I want that if the user click on back press it check that If the `RecyclerView` is visible then it should just close the `RecyclerView` or if it is invisible it should go to another activity.

How I can do it ? Thanks

Comment: In fact, you've described the algorithm to use in your question. You just have to code it now. What is the problem ?

Comment: I am asking that how I will implement this in android studio I have only wrote the recycler View code to show the recycler View now if the recycler View is visible and the person click the back button it just close the recycler View or if the recycler View is not visible then it should go to another activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple you can check the visibilty of the `recyclerView` like

> if ( recyclerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE )

and can can decision what you want to do.

**For Example:** You have to @Override `onBackPressed()` function to manage your logic like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (recyclerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
         //do it here when recyclerview in visible
    } else {
        //go to any activity or 
       //simply supper method will take you on previous activity
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have done something like `recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.something)` already.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (recyclerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);      
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

As suggested by @bruno above, actually you have the answer in mind already. All you have to do is implement it and see if it works.